# Bibliography contents (Journal names) not abbreviated even with IEEEabrv

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am using the following syntax, with no errors or warnings. However, the journal names are still not abbreviated. I compiled the file numerous times, as well as the bibliography. Everything compiles with no errors.

The syntax:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}
```

Additional info:
I am using BibDesk and TeXStudio on a macbook.

**Do you have any idea what might be the issue? and how to solve it?
Thank you.**

Edit:

Example entry from the IEEEabrv file:

```
@STRING{IEEE\_M\_COM        = "{IEEE} Commun. Mag."}
```

Example entry from my references file:

```
@article{dai:2015,
    Author = {Test, T.},
    Journal = {IEEE\_M\_COM },
    Month = {September}
    }
```

Comment: Please show us (a) a couple of representative bib entries in `references.bib` and (b) both the actual and desired forms of the journal names. In particular, do your bib entries contain fields such as `journal = IEEE_J_AC` or, rather, `journal = "{IEEE} Transactions on Automatic Control"`?

Comment: If you want to use the abbreviation, you should have `journal=IEEE_M_COM,` (no braces and no backslashes).

Comment: @egreg but then I get the "missing $ inserted" error because of the underscores

Comment: related: [Underscores in Citation > Error missing $](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303479)

Comment: @Mico I added an example. The IEEEabrv file is compiled/loaded first then my references file. So it should work. Any thoughts why it isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A predefined string should not be inside braces; you must use it literally, in this case with no backslash. TeX won't see the underscores, because BibTeX will do the substitution.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dai:2015,
    Author = {Test, T.},
    Journal = IEEE_M_COM,
    Month = {September}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{dai:2015}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used `filecontents` just for the convenience of a self-contained example. Fix your `references.bib` file and use that.

[image]