# Underscores in Citation > Error missing $

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style

**Problem:** Underscores in my citation file causes the error "missing $ inserted"

**Issue:** I need to keep those underscores (there are too many of them) because they link to the IEEEabrv file which replaces these codes with the abbreviated journal name etc....

**Question:** Do you have a solution that lets me keep tags like "IEEE_J_JLT" and have latex recognize that this, text mode, is different than the math mode *without having to edit all of the instances* and replacing _ with \ _ (backslash underscore)?

Example bib file entry:

```
article{test:2013,
    Author = {Test, D. and Tesssst, J.},
    Journal = {IEEE_J_JLT},
    Month = {April},
    }
```

Comment: `\_` -- usually, but this is only a last resort method. Are you sure that `IEEE_J_JLT` is correct?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes IEEE_J_JLT will be replaced automatically by the appropriate journal abbreviation (the IEEEabrv bib file takes care of that if compiled before the actual reference file). I was hoping that there will be another solution rather than adding backslash each time.

Comment: You shouldn't  do this by yourself. Use Jabref --> http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/JournalAbbreviations.php

Comment: related: [Bibliography contents (Journal names) not abbreviated even with IEEEabrv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303467)

Comment: @Johannes_B how do I close this question? The answer is to remove the braces from {IEEE_J_JLT}

Comment: You can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, Thanks to @egreg, is to remove the braces from `{IEEE_J_JLT}` underscores won't be an issue then.